# How do I convert a DOM object created using `node-htmlparser` back to text?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using [node-htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) to manipulate some HTML. Once I've manipulated the DOM object, how can I convert it back to a text string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). It will offer the typical DOM objects and functions you get in the browser:

```
var jsdom    = require("./lib/jsdom").jsdom,
var document = jsdom("<html><head></head><body>hello world</body></html>");
var html = document.innerHTML;
```